# Are the held-out datasets used for testing, validation or both?

Tags: natural-language-processing, terminology, books, test-datasets, validation-datasets

I came across a new term "held-out corpora" and I confused regarding its usage in the NLP domain

Consider the following three paragraphs from [N-gram Language Models](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/3.pdf)

#1: **held-out corpora as a non-train data**

> For an intrinsic evaluation of a language model we need a test set. As
> with many of the statistical models in our field, the probabilities of
> an $n-$gram model come from the corpus it is trained on, the training
> set or training corpus. We can then measure training set the quality
> of an n-gram model by its performance on some unseen data called the
> test set or test corpus.  **We will also sometimes call test sets and
> other datasets that are not in our training sets held out corpora
> because we hold them out from the held out training data**.

This paragraph clearly says that held-out corpora can be used for either testing or validation or others except training.

#2: **development set or devset for hyperparameter tuning**

> **Sometimes we use a particular test set so often that we implicitly
> tune to its characteristics. We then need a fresh test set that is
> truly unseen. In such cases, we call the initial test set the
> development test set or,devset**. How do we divide our data into
> training, development, and test sets? We want our test set to be as
> large as possible, since a small test set may be accidentally
> unrepresentative, but we also want as much training data as possible.
> At the minimum, we would want to pick the smallest test set that gives
> us enough statistical power to measure a statistically significant
> difference between two potential models. In practice, **we often just
> divide our data into 80% training, 10% development, and 10% test.**
> Given a large corpus that we want to divide into training and test,
> test data can either be taken from some continuous sequence of text
> inside the corpus, or we can remove smaller “stripes” of text from
> randomly selected parts of our corpus and combine them into a test
> set.

This paragraph clearly says that development set is used for hyperparameter tuning.

#3: **held-out corpora for hyperparameter tuning**

> How are these $\lambda$ values set? Both the simple interpolation and
> conditional interpolation $\lambda'$s are learned from a held-out
> corpus.  **A held-out corpus is an additional training corpus that we
> use to set hyperparameters** like these $\lambda$ values, by choosing
> the $\lambda$ values that maximize the likelihood of the held-out
> corpus.

This paragraph is clearly saying that held-out corpus is used for hyper-parameter training.

**I am interpreting or understanding the terms as follows**:

**Train corpus** is used to train the model for learning parameters.

**Test corpus** is used for evaluating the model wrt parameters.

**Development set** is used for evaluating the model wrt hyperparameters.

**Held-out corpus** includes any corpus outside training corpus. So, it can be used for evaluating either parameters or hyperparameters.

To be concise, informally, data = training data + held-out data = training data + development set + test data

Is my understanding true? I got confusion because of paragraph 3, which says that held-out corpus is used (only) for learning the hyperparameters while paragraph 1 says that held-out corpus includes any corpus outside train corpus. Does held-out corpora include devset or same as devset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that these terms may be used *inconsistently* across sources.

If someone says *held-out dataset*, I would immediately think of a dataset that is not used for training, but can be used for anything else, validation (hyper-parameter tuning or early stopping) or testing; so, to determine what they are referring to, I would probably take into account the context.

In your second quote, the *development set* seems to be used as a synonym for *validation dataset* (a more common name to refer to the same concept), i.e. the dataset used for early stopping or hyper-parameter optimization (see also [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/5658/2444)).

So, my answer to your question in the title would be

> Yes, the heldout dataset can be used for validation or testing, but not because it's a special dataset, but because people may use this term to refer to either the validation dataset or the test dataset.

Here's another example of the usage of the term *held-out set* to refer, in this case, to the validation dataset (section 1.6 of [this famous ML book](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf))

> The results above suggest a simple way of achieving this, namely by taking the available data and partitioning it into a training set, used to determine the coefficients $\mathbf{w}$, and a *separate* validation set, also called a **hold-out set**, used to *optimize the model complexity*

Here's another example that shows that the term may be used inconsistently (emphasis mine, taken from [section 5.3](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html) of the famous deep learning book by Goodfellow et al.). In fact, in that same section, they refer to the validation dataset, which is distinct from this **held-out test set** (so, in this case, the held-out set is used to refer only to the test set).

> Earlier we discussed how a **held-out test set**, composed of examples coming from the same distribution as the training set, can be used to estimate the generalization error of a learner, after the learning process has completed.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample dataset, the variable Sprint is the respondent's time (in seconds) to sprint a given distance, and Smoking is an indicator about whether or not the respondent smokes (0 = Nonsmoker, 1 = Past smoker, 2 = Current smoker). Use ANOVA to test if there is a statistically significant difference in sprint time with respect to smoking status. Sprint time will serve as the dependent variable, and smoking status will act as the independent variable.